# How to send chat messages using converse library

Tags: javascript, xmpp, chat, openfire, converse.js

I am using openfire as an XMPP server and using converse as client library. I want to send a chat message from my chat window to openfire. For this I want to send the text to a converse method which will send the message to the XMPP server.
I am trying to send the message using the following:

```
var msg = converse.env.$msg({
      from: 'a1@localhost',
      to: 'a6@localhost',
      type: 'chat',
      body: "Hi"
   });
   converse.send(msg);
```

But this sends the following frame in network of console in websocket:

> message from='a1@localhost' to='a6@localhost' type='chat' body='Hi' xmlns='jabber:client'/>

This does not transfer message to the other user neither it stores it in the table. I am pretty much sure I am calling a wrong function. Can anyone povide any help.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the right function.

What you'll probably miss:

1. Listener of messages in "a6@localhost" client: as I read in documentation there are few functions
2. Probably, the right name of server. "localhost" has problem. You can
   check Openfire for real service name on his own web panel
3. To check if a message it's delivered in Openfire you'll can check
   OF's log (check debug one, but probably you'll have to enable it).
   Real time messages are not stored on database, only groupchat's ones
   and not everytime AND offline messages. To not find them on db means nothing

https://conversejs.org/docs/html/development.html

```
converse.chats.open('buddy@example.com');
converse.chats.get('buddy@example.com');
converse.listen.on('message', function (event, messageXML) { ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is wrong. conversejs uses strophe plugin to construct and send messages. It exposes the strophe $msg message builder for constructing stanzas. It has to be in the following format:

```
converse.env.$msg({from: 'a1@localhost', to: 'a6@localhost', type: 'chat'}).c('body').t('Hi');
```

You need to add a body node and within it a text node for the message.

You can also create and add your own api method and internally create a method that sends your custom stanza, and expose it using the api.